# Updated to ubuntu studio 17.10 volume control shortcuts not working

Tags: sound, shortcut-keys, 17.10, ubuntu-studio

Updated to Ubuntu Studio 17.10 and my volume control shortcuts are no longer workning. They either are extreeemly slow or not working at all. The mute button worked a couple of minutes after pressing it but then I couldn'n unmute.

The volume up/down dont work at all.

Everything works with clicking though.

edit: seems like the buttons do work but with a latency of at least 5 minutes which I find weird 'cause the other button shortcuts work instantly.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. My problem was that I was using the Unity GNOME, because I like it better, instead of the new Xorg one. Switching to the new one again solved the problem for me.

Comment: @zgk What do you mean by "the new Xorg one"? Can you explain how you switched (or switched back) to solve the problem? I recommend that you **[edit]** this answer to include that information.